What is the best way to access object of subclass in other subclass?
Attached is a minimum working example of a problem I have:
class A():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.b=B(self)
        self.c=C(self)
        
        
class B():
    def __init__(self, parent):
    
        self.a1=3
    
class C():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        self.a2=4
        
        print(B.a1)
    
    def ab():
        print(B.a1)

C(object).ab()

What is the best way to access in class C the object of class B?
In principle, I built a TKinter App with every frame being a class and I want in one frame to access the variable of another frame.
EDIT @all thank you all fpr the input. I expanded the minimum working example to my specific problem:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox


class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("xxx")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        
        #Build GUI
        self.inputframe = INPUTframe(self)
        self.imregframe = IMREGframe(self)
        self.calcframe = CALCframe(self)

class INPUTframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=150):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0, y=0)
        
        label= ttk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12))
        label.place(x=10,y=0)

        self.create_widgets()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label1.place(x=30,y=30)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx',command = lambda: self.path(1))
        button1.place(x=100,y=30)
        self.textentry1=tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable= self.textentry1)
        self.entry1.place(x=160,y=30,width="350")
        label11 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label11.place(x=500,y=30)
        
    def path(self,var):

        match var:
           case 1:
               self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
               filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,title='Choose a file')
               self.entry1.insert("end",filename)
               return filename

class IMREGframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=250, height=150):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0,y=150)

        label4 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12))
        label4.place(x=10,y=0)
        
        self.SFAtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        
        self.create_widgets()      
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        #self.SFAtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        checkb1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx', variable=self.SFAtrue, onvalue=0, offvalue=1)
        checkb1.place(x=30,y=30)
        checkb2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx', variable=self.SFAtrue, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        checkb2.place(x=30,y=50)
 

class CALCframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=100):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0,y=370)
        self.parent=parent
        
        self.create_widgets()
        
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx', command = lambda: self.calculate(self.parent.imregframe.SFAtrue.get())) #bester Weg um Variabele aus anderer Klasse/Objekt zu holen?
        button4.config( height = 4, width = 12 )
        button4.place(x=50,y=0)

        self.Previewtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        checkb3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx',variable=self.Previewtrue, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        checkb3.place(x=150,y=0)
        label5 = tk.Label(self,text="xxx", font=("Arial", 9))
        label5.place(x=150,y=30)
        label51 = tk.Label(self,text="xxx", font=("Arial", 9))
        label51.place(x=150,y=50)
        
    def calculate (self, calcType):
        
        print(calcType)
        print(self.parent.inputframe.textentry1.get())
    
main_window().mainloop()  

The thin I was missing was self.parent=parent as suggested by @Obaskly and it works now. Is this a good way to do it? The variables get quite long: self.parent.inputframe.textentry1.get()

You can allow a class to pass a reference to itself to another class by exposing its "self" as a property or through a method. Generally you don't want classes to give away everything about themselves this way, but it can work (the downside is things outside that class can basically mess with everything about the class, if you are too loose about passing such references around). Better perhaps would be if the classes only allowed access to those things it contains that are meant to be shared.

so you want to access the B instance from C?

@topsail how could that look like? And specifically the limiting the certain attributes?

@Obaskly Yes, exactly

You need a bit more code to be a minimal example: You state that your tkinter app has multiple frames, but your posted code does not instantiate multiple classes.

You can only access an attribute of a class via an instance of the class.  For your posted code, there is no instance of class B created.

Actually you don't need self.parent = parent because self.master will be created implicitly and refers to the parent.

There are two things wrong with your code:

You are trying to access B.a1, which is incorrect because a1 is an instance variable, not a class variable. You should access it through the instance of B, which is held by A.

The ab() method inside C should accept self as the first parameter to be an instance method.


You need to maintain a reference to the B instance created in the A class.
It should look like this, so that the C class can access the B instance and its attributes via its parent A.
class A():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.c = C(self)


class B():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.a1 = 3 


class C():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent  # Reference to the parent class
        self.a2 = 4
        print(self.parent.b.a1)  # Access B's a1 via the parent

    def ab(self):
        print(self.parent.b.a1) 


# Create an instance of A
instance_of_A = A()

# Access method ab() of class C through instance of A
instance_of_A.c.ab()

EDIT
The variable names can become quite long, that's for sure. There are few techniques you can use. Like using references, for example you can create shortcut references to frequently accessed widgets or variables.
class CALCframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=100):
        # ...
        
        # Shortcut references
        self.imregframe = self.parent.imregframe
        self.inputframe = self.parent.inputframe
        
        self.create_widgets()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx', command=lambda: self.calculate(self.imregframe.SFAtrue.get()))
        button4.config(height=4, width=12)
        button4.place(x=50, y=0)
        
        # ...
        
    def calculate(self, calcType):
        print(calcType)
        print(self.inputframe.textentry1.get())

Or you can use a controller Class; that holds the state of your application and allows frames to interact through it.
class AController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = main_window(self)
        
    def get_SFAtrue(self):
        return self.main_window.imregframe.SFAtrue.get()
    
    def get_textentry1(self):
        return self.main_window.inputframe.textentry1.get()

class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.controller = controller
        self.title("xxx")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        
        self.inputframe = INPUTframe(self)
        self.imregframe = IMREGframe(self)
        self.calcframe = CALCframe(self)

class CALCframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=100):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.controller = parent.controller
        
        self.create_widgets()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx', command=self.calculate)
        button4.config(height=4, width=12)
        button4.place(x=50, y=0)
        
    def calculate(self):
        calcType = self.controller.get_SFAtrue()
        textEntry1 = self.controller.get_textentry1()
        print(calcType)
        print(textEntry1)

AController()


thank you. It seems I was missing this self.parent = parent. I added an extended minimium example to my question. Could you please look at it if it is the best way?

@TMul I edited my answer with some suggestions

@Oblasky, thank you

If you want to avoid the long chains of dots and better comply with the Law of Demeter, I would have the main class pass the variables rather than require the other classes to extract them.
Ideally CALCframe should not need to know the internals of main_window, INPUTframe, and IMREGframe. Otherwise, if you decide to reuse CALCframe in else where or need to nest it further, it will stop working.
In your specific case, an easy way to get around this is to have main_window pass INPUTframe and IMREGframe's Tkinter variables to CALCframe. This decouples CALCframe and lets you use it with any parent so long as you pass the appropriate variables.
Here's your code updated to show what I mean:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox


class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("xxx")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        
        #Build GUI
        self.inputframe = INPUTframe(self)
        self.imregframe = IMREGframe(self)
        self.calcframe = CALCframe(self, self.inputframe.textentry1, self.imregframe.SFAtrue)

class INPUTframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=150):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0, y=0)
        
        label= ttk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12))
        label.place(x=10,y=0)

        self.create_widgets()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label1.place(x=30,y=30)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx',command = lambda: self.path(1))
        button1.place(x=100,y=30)
        self.textentry1=tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable= self.textentry1)
        self.entry1.place(x=160,y=30,width="350")
        label11 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label11.place(x=500,y=30)
        
    def path(self,var):

        match var:
           case 1:
               self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
               filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,title='Choose a file')
               self.entry1.insert("end",filename)
               return filename

class IMREGframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=250, height=150):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0,y=150)

        label4 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12))
        label4.place(x=10,y=0)
        
        self.SFAtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        
        self.create_widgets()      
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        #self.SFAtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
        checkb1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx', variable=self.SFAtrue, onvalue=0, offvalue=1)
        checkb1.place(x=30,y=30)
        checkb2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx', variable=self.SFAtrue, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        checkb2.place(x=30,y=50)
 

class CALCframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, textentry1, SFAtrue, width=800, height=100):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0,y=370)
        self.parent=parent

        self.SFAtrue = SFAtrue
        self.textentry1 = textentry1
        
        self.create_widgets()
        
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx', command = lambda: self.calculate(self.SFAtrue.get())) #bester Weg um Variabele aus anderer Klasse/Objekt zu holen?
        button4.config( height = 4, width = 12 )
        button4.place(x=50,y=0)

        self.Previewtrue=tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        checkb3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='xxx',variable=self.Previewtrue, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        checkb3.place(x=150,y=0)
        label5 = tk.Label(self,text="xxx", font=("Arial", 9))
        label5.place(x=150,y=30)
        label51 = tk.Label(self,text="xxx", font=("Arial", 9))
        label51.place(x=150,y=50)
        
    def calculate (self, calcType):
        
        print(calcType)
        print(self.textentry1.get())
    
main_window().mainloop()



thank you very much! That seems good. I will try it.
